# Is it possible to combine resourcestrings in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I want to replace code that looks like

```
resourcestring
    RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN = 'Error 1. Please try again.';
    RESSTR_ERR2_TRYAGAIN = 'Error 2. Please try again.';
    RESSTR_ERR3_TRYAGAIN = 'Error 3. Please try again.';
```

with something like this:

```
resourcestring
    RESSTR_ERR1 = 'Error 1.';
    RESSTR_ERR2 = 'Error 2.';
    RESSTR_ERR3 = 'Error 3.';        
    RESSTR_TRYAGAIN = 'Please try again.'; 

    RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN = RESSTR_ERR1 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN; //error
    RESSTR_ERR2_TRYAGAIN = RESSTR_ERR2 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN;
    RESSTR_ERR3_TRYAGAIN = RESSTR_ERR3 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN;
```

But this leads to error `E2026 Constant expression expected.`, what I do understand.

Nevertheless, I wonder if there is a solution, that allows me to define `RESSTR_ERRx_TRYAGAIN` in the way described above. (The goal is to eliminate the additional translations without touching all the places where RESSTR_ERRx_TRYAGAIN is used).

My only idea until now is the following, but I don't want to use this, because this is rather ugly:

```
var
    RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN: string;
    //...

initialization
    RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN := RESSTR_ERR1 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN;
    //...
```

Comment: The real strings are more complicated, this example is only for illustration.

Comment: I would declare functions to return the strings

Comment: You can format the string at run-time: `Format('%S %S',[RESSTR_ERR1,RESSTR_TRYAGAIN])`.

Comment: @LURD Acknowledged. But I would like to avoid modifying all the places where the resourcestring is already used.

Comment: Then do as David suggested. Make `RESSTR_ERRx_TRYAGAIN` a function.

Comment: @LURD Yes, I think, that's what I'm gonna do.

Comment: Not really makes much DRY sense, since basically `RESSTR_ERR1 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN`, `RESSTR_ERR2 + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN` etc would put redundant data into string table(s). Remember, `resourcestring` syntax is a *sugar* for composing `RT_STRING` resource entries.

Comment: @FreeConsulting If [my proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37828766/2306907) is used, there is no redundant data in the string table. The same is true, if `RESSTR_ERRx_TRYAGAIN` is declared as function as suggested by David Heffernan.

Answer (score 5):

`resourcestring` strings are resolved at *runtime*.  Every time you reference a resourcestring what is actually happening is that you are calling the **LoadResString()** API to load the (potentially) translated string from the application resources.

`const` declarations are constants, which must be fully defined at compile-time.

Even a typed constant (technically a variable, subject to compiler settings) must be initially fully defined at compile time, even though it may be potentially later modified at runtime.  There is no mechanism to automatically update constants based on translations that are applied at runtime.

Even if you could combine resource strings in the way that you are trying, you do not save any translation because any declared combination of resource strings would itself have to be a resource string, requiring a separate translation for that combination:

```
resourcestring
   foo = 'foo.';  // Requires translation of 'foo.'
   bar = 'bar';   // Requires translation of 'bar'
   foobar = foo + bar   // Would require translation of 'foo.bar'
```

Of course, as you have discovered, that third declaration is not possible, but it would not save you the additional translation even if it were.

The reason you cannot use a constant to hold the combined, translated values is that these are not constant:

```
resourcestring
   foo = 'foo.';  // Requires translation of 'foo.'
   bar = 'bar';   // Requires translation of 'bar'

const
   foobar = foo + bar   // When referenced, foo and bar are actually calls to a function and so are not constant
```

If you are concerned primarily with reducing work in declaring your constants, then you could use this:

```
const
  foo = 'foo.';
  bar = 'bar';

resourcestring
  foobar = foo + bar;
```

But you still then need to provide for all the resulting resource strings with their complete constant parts and so fails to achieve the goal of avoiding additional translations.

### Problems with Constant Solutions

Any solution which contrives to enable declaration of a combined `resourcestring` will demand a separate translation for that specific combination achieving little/no benefit (actually creating more work: the additional translations).

Any solution which contrives to declare a constant using the *compile-time* values of the resource string will not be translated at run-time.

Your work-around with **initialization** suffers from a rather more subtle complication which is that your initialized pseudo-constants will contain the translated values of the resource strings at the time of initialization.  If you are using something like Sisulizer which allows runtime changes of i18n resources then any such changes will not be reflected in your pseudo-constants.

You could still use this technique,but place your initialization code in a function which you call at **initialization** *and* if/when-ever the translation language is changed at runtime.

### Runtime Solutions for Runtime Problems

As explained, the underlying problem is that you are trying to declare a *compile-time* constant composed of values that are only resolved at *run-time*.

What you need instead is a convenient, reliable mechanism to combine two runtime values *at runtime*.

If the 'try again' example is an isolated case then a simple function to append a specific resource string to some other specified string (which may be a resource string, or may not) might suffice:

```
function MessageWithTranslatedTryAgain(const aMessage: String): String;
begin
  if aMessage[Length(aMessage)] <> '.' then
    result := aMessage + '. ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN
  else
    result := aMessage + ' ' + RESSTR_TRYAGAIN;
end;
```

If you have a number of such possible combinations then you might instead choose to implement a class with a number of static utility methods:

```
type
  Translate = class
  public
    class function MessageWithTryAgain(const aMessage: String): String;
    class function MessageWithContinue(const aMessage: String): String;
    // etc
  end;
```

Comment: You are right, my original solution, which tried to set the strings at compile time did compile but was not translated. I modified [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37828766/2306907) to work correctly. +1 for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using a record and operator overloading:

```
interface

type
    TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings = record
        Part1: PResStringRec;
        Part2: PResStringRec;
        class operator Implicit(From: TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings): string;
    end;

resourcestring
    RESSTR_ERR1 = 'Error 1.';
    RESSTR_ERR2 = 'Error 2.';
    RESSTR_ERR3 = 'Error 3.';
    RESSTR_TRYAGAIN = 'Please try again.';             

const
    RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN: TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings 
      = (Part1: @RESSTR_ERR1; Part2: @RESSTR_TRYAGAIN);    
    RESSTR_ERR2_TRYAGAIN: TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings 
      = (Part1: @RESSTR_ERR2; Part2: @RESSTR_TRYAGAIN);    
    RESSTR_ERR3_TRYAGAIN: TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings 
      = (Part1: @RESSTR_ERR3; Part2: @RESSTR_TRYAGAIN);    


implementation

class operator TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings.Implicit(From: TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings): string;
begin
    Result := LoadResString(From.Part1) + ' ' + LoadResString(From.Part2);
end;
```

Usage:

```
ShowMessage(RESSTR_ERR1_TRYAGAIN);
```

I tested this with dxgettext and it is translated correctly.

<sub>(The original idea to define `Part1` and `Part2`as `string` does not always work (as Deltics pointed out): It does compile but is not translated correctly if the language is switched at runtime.)</sub>

Comment: Is `TSpaceSeparatedResourceStrings` supposed to be a `class` or a `record` in your example? The code is missing that definition, and both can have overloaded operators.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Awrr, so many errors in that little bit of code: A record. The operator function was wrong too... And of course this isn't a record helper. Fixed it.

Comment: Very clever, I like it!

Comment: This is essentially just a more complex alternative to the `initialization` section approach already mooted by the OP.  The `initialization` section is simply moved into the (more cumbersome) declaration of each constant.  But like the `initialization` approach, it will not behave correctly if the language is changed at runtime (which may or may not be a problem now or in the future, but is a potential problem).  Explicitly initialized variables can at least be re-initialized if the language is changed (should that be required) which this `const` workaround does *not* allow.

Comment: @Deltics That is not correct! LoadResString is called everytime the constant is *used* (eg when calling `ShowMessage`), not in the initialization section. It *will behave correctly* if the language is changed at runtime (if the underlying system supports runtime-switching of the language). I had modified my original answer to address exactly this problem.

Comment: @Yonojoy - oops, yes, you're quite right.  It's been a while since I actually used resourcestrings.  Clearly some dusting is needed in the ol' memory banks.  :)